# How do I connect to my SQL express server 2012 from Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I have set up an SQL Express server, I can query it remotely using a python script - so I know all of the permissions are set up correctly for remote access.

However I am struggling to get the same query to work in Node JS. The code I am using looks like this:

```
const mssql = require('mssql')
const config = {
    "host": "myhost",
    "user": "myuser",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "mydb"
}

async function sql_new(){
    mssql.connect(config);
    var request = new msql.Request();
    console.log(await request.query("select * from mytable"));

}
sql_new()
```

This returns the following error:

ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'myuser'. I am 100% sure the credentials are correct, and a colleague of mine is getting the same error

Comment: I don't know if this could be the issue, but I've never used the syntax you're using with mssql. I use something more akin to the syntax shown [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/access-sql-server-in-nodejs)

Comment: @silencedogood I get the exact same error

Comment: Not sure then. Obviously tcp/ip is enable being as you connected with python. I've had to set the tdsVersion to connect to an old sql 2000 instance, but you shouldn't need that with 2012...